# Java Key-Value Collection with complexity of O(1) for millions of random unordered keys

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, time-complexity, keyvaluepair

I am stuck with a problem where I have millions of key-value pairs that I need to access using the keys randomly (not by using an iterator).

The range of keys is not known at compile time, but total number of the key-value pairs is known.

I have looked into **HashMap** and **Hashset** data structures but they are not truly **O(1)** as in case of collision in the hash-code they become array of **LinkedLists** which has linear search complexity at worst case.

I have also considered increasing the number of **buckets** in the **HashMap** but it does not ensure that every element will be stored in a separate bucket.

Is there any way to store and access millions of key-value pairs with **O(1)** complexity?

Ideally I would like every key to be like a variable and corresponding value should be the value assigned to that key

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have **any** evidence, such as an information theoretic argument or measurements, that your data causes so much collision that lookup is no longer O(1) time? If not, then you're worrying about nothing.

Comment: can you try using hash of key and value together and store it as key in hash table, I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: @Nachiket That both defeats the purpose of a key-value collection (can't look up the value from the key, need to know it to look it up) and introduces *more* possibilities for hash collisions, not fewer.

Comment: @delnan in terms of evidence, I know there will be millions of values in the range 1 to some billions and they will occur randomly so I can not write a good **Hash** function which means I don't know how many keys will be hashed to a **bucket**

Comment: in Java 8 HashMap will use some kind of balanced tree instead of lists to handle collisions. Also try with better hash function.

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/180

Comment: I agree with the hashing part...it seems that the guava implementation of the Hash does the trick - never tried it though: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v14.0/javadoc/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html

Comment: @Kami That doesn't make sense. None of what you say hints at a higher-than-expected collision likelihood and writing good hash functions is mostly independent of these concerns anyway (since you want it to work well for all kinds of data, and not knowing much about the keys is actually the default). Just friggin' try it. Bet you it'll work just fine?

Comment: I still think you should think over what @delnan said. Are you actually observing non-**O(1)** time complexity on your data?

For data sizes much larger than 4,294,967,296 solution would be to make a Hashtable implementation using long hashes instead of int hashes. That would let your data set be as large as 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 with a low chance of collisions.

Comment: @delnan I will give it a try with the default hash function and let you guys know about the results.. thanks a lot all of you for your quick help

Comment: @Kami You are more likely to see a slow down due to the fact your data no longer fits in the CPU caches.  Accessing main memory randomly can be 50x slower than accessing memory in the L1 cache.  By comparison, one million keys I would expect to be about 1.6x slower for reasonable assumptions about collision rate.  BTW HashMap doesn't use LinkedList.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Cache misses are everywhere, a million element hashmap is not much more likely to cause them than ordinary object access, a thousand element hash table, or random access in a thousand element array, to give a few examples. What's more, often it's surprisingly hard to predict the magnitude of these effects, and even harder to improve them without radically restructing your algorithm. This is the equivalent of telling an architect to worry about kids spraying graffitis as opposed to worrying about getting the building done.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ALso, HashMap does use a linked list for the buckets, in any version I checked at least. It doesn't use a `java.util.LinkedList`, but that's not saying much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing what Big O notation represents.  It defines limiting behavior of a function, not necessarily actual behavior.

The average complexity of a hash map is O(1) for insert, delete, and search operations.  What does this mean?  In means, on average, those operations will complete in constant time regardless of the size of the hash map.  So, depending on the implementation of the map, a lookup might not take exactly one step but it will most likely not involve more than a few steps, relative to the hash map's size.

How well a hash map actually behaves for those operations is determined by a few factors.  The most obvious is the hash function used to bucket keys.  Hash functions that distribute the computed hashes more uniformly over the hash range and limit the number of collisions are preferred.  The better the hash function in those areas, the closer a hash map will actually operate in constant time.

Another factor that affects actual hash map behavior is how storage is managed.  How a map resizes and repositions entries as items are added and removed helps control hash collisions by using an optimal number of buckets.  Managing the hash map storage affectively will allow the hash map to operate close to constant time.

With all that said, there are ways to construct hash maps that have O(1) worst case behavior for lookups.  This is accomplished using a [perfect hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).  A perfect hash function is an invertible 1-1 function between keys and hashes.  With a perfect hash function and the proper hash map storage, O(1) lookups can be achieved.  The prerequisite for using this approach is knowing all the key values in advance so a perfect hash function can be developed.

Sadly, your case does not involve known keys so a perfect hash function can not be constructed but, the available research might help you construct a near perfect hash function for your case.

Comment: Would this be helpful if I say I am using **Integer** as keys and range will be 1 to some billion but at one time **HashMap** will have few million random integers from that range as keys

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such a (known) data structure for generic data types.

If there were, it would most likely have replaced hash tables in most commonly-used libraries, unless there's some significant disadvantage like a massive constant factor or ridiculous memory usage, either of which would probably make it nonviable for you as well.

I said "generic data types" above, as there may be some specific special cases for which it's possible, such as when the key is a integer in a small range - in this case you could just have an array where each index corresponds to the same key, but this is also really a hash table where the key hashes to itself.

---

Note that you need a terrible hash function, the [pathological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathological_%28mathematics%29#Computer_science) input for your hash function, or a very undersized hash table to actually get the worst-case O(n) performance for your hash table. You really should test it and see if it's fast enough before you go in search of something else. You could also try `TreeMap`, which, with its O(log n) operations, will sometimes outperform `HashMap`.